# Error in MySQL query, but can't find out why?

Tags: mysql

I am having an error in my MySQL query and can't seem to find whats wrong? Further more, a different query on the same table works fine with just minor changes.

I have a table, `site_users`, that contains the connection between sites and users. It has two fields:

- site_id - int(6)
- user_id - int(6)

The primary key is `site_id + user_id`.

---

**QUERY 1:** The following query is not working:

```
INSERT INTO `site_users` (site_id, user_id) VALUES (1, 3); DELETE FROM `site_users` WHERE (site_id, user_id) IN ((1, 2));
```

**! Note that I execute 2 queries at once !**

The error message is (code 1064):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELETE FROM `site_users` WHERE (site_id, user_id) IN ((1,
>   2))' at line 1

**QUERY 2:** The strange thing is that when creating a query in a different view, the query  works fine?

```
INSERT INTO `site_users` (user_id, site_id) VALUES (1, 2); DELETE FROM `site_users` WHERE (user_id, site_id) IN ((1, 3));
```

---

What is wrong with the first query?

Comment: You should be able to eyeball the differences

Answer (score -1):

Try using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `site_users` (`site_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (1, 3), DELETE FROM `site_users` WHERE (`site_id`, `user_id`) IN ((1, 2));
```